# How to run a function on a lambda parameter to be used in a nested lambda in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda, conditional-statements, filtering, anonymous-function

*background (from comments):*

I don't want to have to use the same functions twice per element for the two conditionals i.e `\x -> f (g x) == .. && f (g x) == ..` so I'm trying to find a way to do `\y -> y == .. && y -> == ..` where `y = f (g x)`.

*original post:*

I want to filter a list that requires functions to be run on each element before multiple conditionals can be tested.

I've would like to create an expression following this structure:

```
filter (\x -> (\y -> y == cond0 && y == cond1) f . g) $ ..
```

where `f . g x` provides input to `y` for evaluation.

The actual code reads as follows:

```
filter (\x -> (\y -> 
  fromJust (accessorFunc0 y) == foo && compareFunc bar (accessorFun1 y)) f . g) $ accessorFun2 dataStruc
```

but I've also tried:

```
filter ((\x -> 
  fromJust (accessorFunc0 y) == foo && compareFunc bar (accessorFun1 y)) f . g) $ accessorFun2 dataStruc
```

which also produces compiler errors.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. But the fundamental problem is that, in `filter (\x -> whatever)`, `whatever` must be a *boolean* expression. And what you have there, no matter what is in the "inner lambda", is currently bound to be a *function*, since it uses the composition operator `.`.

Comment: Could you give more specifics of the particular problem you are solving? This could help clarify your question.

Comment: I don't want to have to use the same functions twice per element for the two conditionals i.e `\x -> f (g x) == .. && f (g x) == ..` so I'm trying to find a way to do `\y -> y == .. && y -> == ..` where `y = f (g x)`

Comment: you meant `(\x -> (\y -> y == cond0 && y == cond1) . f . g $ x)`. shorter written as `(\y -> y == cond0 && y == cond1) . f . g)` (as the answer by @chi shows), but easier and clearer and simpler written as `(\x -> let { y = f (g x) } in y == cond0 && y == cond1)`. so, the short answer is, use `let`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling (\y -> ...) with argument `f` here:

```
filter (\x -> (\y -> 
  fromJust (accessorFunc0 y) == foo && compareFunc bar (accessorFun1 y)) f . g) $ accessorFun2 dataStruc
```

Also, the `\x ->` does not help, since the composition will already produce a function.

You might be looking for something like

```
filter (
  (\y -> fromJust (accessorFunc0 y) == foo && compareFunc bar (accessorFun1 y))
  . f
  . g) $ accessorFun2 dataStruc
```

where `f` is composed with `\y -> ...` instead of passed as an argument.

Beware that `fromJust` is partial, and will crash the program on `Nothing`.